# How to count the price from a list of options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, logic, expo

I'm learning react native with expo by trying to do a Food App. Right now I'm building the Extras Screen, where the customer can add cheese, bacon and so on to his order. To render the options I'm using SectionList. Everything looks pretty good, but how do I properly code the plus and minus buttons logic so that it changes the "0"s? And how to read these values and multiply by each one prices to get the correct ORDER NOW value? I'm really lost now.

[image: App Screen]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Text,Thumbnail, CheckBox, View, Image, Input, StyleProvider,Form, Label, Item, ListItem, Badge, List, Textarea, Segment  } from 'native-base';
import { StyleSheet, ImageComponent, SectionList } from 'react-native';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import { Entypo, Feather, FontAwesome5, MaterialCommunityIcons, FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { RFPercentage, RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';




const Extra = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>

    <Body style={styles.bodylistaextra}>

      <Text style={styles.nomeextra}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text note numberOfLines={1} style={styles.preçoextra}>{"$ " + item.preco}</Text>

    </Body>

    <View style={styles.viewQuantidade}>
      <Button transparent >
        <AntDesign name='minuscircleo' style={styles.iconediminuirextra}></AntDesign>
      </Button>

      <Form>
        <Textarea style={styles.caixaquantidade} rowSpan={1} bordered placeholder="0" />
      </Form>

      <Button icon transparent >
        <AntDesign name='pluscircleo' style={styles.iconeaumentarextra}></AntDesign>
      </Button>
    </View>

  </View>
);


export default class ItemPSScreen extends Component {


  render() {

    const {route} = this.props;
    const { item } = route.params;

    return (


    <Container>

        <SectionList
          ListHeaderComponent={
            <Content>
              <Thumbnail square style={styles.imagemitem} source={{uri: 'https://iguatemi.com.br/brasilia/sites/brasilia/files/styles/crop_blog_1920x720/public/2019-11/Madero%20%281%29_0.png?h=e6fdde1b&itok=CSnKh7nl'}} />

              <View style={{width: wp('95%'), alignSelf:'center'}}>

                <Text style={styles.tituloitem}>{item.name}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.descricaoitem}>{item.descricao}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.valoritem}>{"$ " + item.preco}</Text>

              </View>
            </Content>
          }
          sections={item.extraOptions}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Extra item={item} />}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <List>
              <ListItem itemDivider style={styles.itemdivisoria}>
                <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
              </ListItem>      
            </List>
          )}
          ListFooterComponent={
            <Content>
            <MaterialIcons name='chat' style={styles.iconeobservacao}></MaterialIcons>

            <Text style={styles.textoobservacao} >Observações:</Text>

            <Form>

              <Textarea style={styles.caixaobservacao} rowSpan={5} bordered placeholder="Tirar cebola, tirar o molho, sem sal, etc." />

            </Form>


            <Button style={styles.botaopedir}>

              <Text style={styles.textopedir}>ORDER NOW</Text>

              <Text style={styles.valortotalpedido}>{"$ " + item.preco}</Text>

            </Button>
            </Content>
          }/>

    </Container>

    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

for each item it looks like you have an object which is good like so:

```
item: {
  tituloitem: 'bacon'
  descricaoitem: ''
}
```

when the particular item is added to the cart by the user you should add an extra object key field like `quantity`. and set it to `1` as we know that if they've added it, there will be at least one quantity

```
item: {
  tituloitem: 'bacon'
  descricaoitem: '',
  quantity: 1, 
}
```

you then should at some state to this component:

`const Extra = ({ item }) => (`
by adding `const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0)

`<Textarea style={styles.caixaquantidade} rowSpan={1} bordered placeholder="0" />`

to include `quantity`

`<Textarea style={styles.caixaquantidade} rowSpan={1} bordered placeholder="0" value={quantity}/>`

then here: `<AntDesign name='pluscircleo' style={styles.iconeaumentarextra}></AntDesign>` you should add an `onChange` listener to increment the quantity by doing `setQuantity(quantity + 1)` (obviously do the same for minus too

then you want to have a function that works out the total price of your whole basket and that function should be listening or called when extras are added

you could have an `updateBasket` function that grabs the current total, updates it and then shows the new total

let me know if that helps

Comment: In this case I cant add: "const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0)" inside const Extra. It would work if it was a function component, right?

Comment: yeh exactly , change it to a func component and that should work

Comment: Why "onChange" on AntDesign and not "onPress" inside Button?

Comment: ah it probably is `onPress`, I'm not familiar with `onPress` but yeh use that

Comment: The button is working fine, but the item that I send to <Extra> is a copy of the original one? I'm changing the quantity but, I cant get it to print in my class component

Comment: I just realized that when I use `item.quantity = item.quantity + 1;` inside the `AntDesign` I can get this changed value inside ORDER NOW. But the value does not refresh automaticaly. Im trying to do what you said with an updateBasket function, but for now I'm not being sucessfull

Answer (score 1):

At first, I think each of your "item" will have addition property called `quantity` to indicate the number of your item will be adjusted.

And you can stored your "item" in component state to update screen UI when state changed.

Then when user click on plus or minus button, you just need to increase / decrease the `quantity` property of your item then set it back to state.

Finally, to calculate the total price, just take sum of all item `price` * `quantity`

Check my code:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const {route} = this.props;
    let { item } = route.params;

    let {extraOptions} = item;

    extraOptions= extraOptions.map((option) => {
        option.quantity = 0;
        return option;
    });

    item.extraOptions = extraOptions;

    this.setState({
        item,
    })
}

 render() {
     let extraOptions = (this.state.item) ? this.state.item.extraOptions : [];
     return (
         <Container>

             <SectionList
                ... 
                sections={extraOptions}
                ...
             />
         </Container>
     );
  }

  const Extra = ({ item, index }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
        ...
        <View style={styles.viewQuantidade}>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => {
                let {item} = this.state;
                let {extraOptions} = item;

                extraOptions[index].quantity = extraOptions[index].quantity - 1;
                item.extraOptions = extraOptions;
                this.setState({
                    item,
                });
            }}>
                ....
            <Button icon transparent onPress={() => {
                let {item} = this.state;
                let {extraOptions} = item;

                extraOptions[index].quantity = extraOptions[index].quantity + 1;
                item.extraOptions = extraOptions;
                this.setState({
                    item,
                });
            }} >
                ...
            </Button>
        </View>

    </View>
);
```

Hope that help :)